# Postgres JSONB[] (Array of JsonB) Support with Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I have a column in my DB of type JSONB[]. This is a DB array of JSONB objects, supported by PostGre sql.

(NB: This is not the same as a JSON array of objects represented as JSONB.)

I want to represent this column as a Hibernate entity.

For the sake of example, a table called items where each item has a column called "reviews" which is of type JsonB[].

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Item {
  
  List<Review> reviews; 

} 

//....elsewhere
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Review implements Serializable { 
  String reviewText;
  String reviewer; 
}
```

I have tried using Vlad Mihalcea's Hypersistence Utils Hibernate Types https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils

but it only supports either JsonB or Json or a simple Array type String[] but not an array of JsonB  .

Attempting to run the code as is gives unable to deserialize the resulting string from Postgres to my type of List

Comment: `jsonb[]` pretty much never makes sense - JPA or not.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm building on top of a preexisting table used by an other app and am unable to change the datatype here.